# rails serialize not saving as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to serialize a field as a hash, but for some reason it saves it as a ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn rather than a yaml hash.

Table:

```
DESCRIBE classifications;
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dynamic_fields | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Model:

```
class Classification
  serialize :dynamic_fields, Hash
end
```

Console:

```
c = Classification.new
c.code = 'some_code'
c.dynamic_fields = { '0' => {'field'=>'a','type'=>1}, '1' => {'field'=>'b','type'=>2} }
=> #<struct ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute coder=#<ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn:0x007fa69890fd58 @object_class=Hash>, value="---\n'0':\n  field: a\n  type: 1\n'1':\n  field: b\n  type: 2\n", state=:serialized>
```

I have no idea why it is trying to save this as a ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn rather than a Hash, since I specified Hash to serialize. How can I resolve this?

I just discovered WHAT is causing the issue, but not WHY:

In my Classification model, I included the following:

```
module MongoidDocumenter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    all.each do |class_code|
      has_many_documents "#{class_code.code.underscore}_field".to_sym
    end
  end
end
```

When I comment it out, the problem goes away:

```
# include MongoidDocumenter
```

The has_many_documents dynamically builds methods:

```
    class_eval <<-EOS
      def #{ association_name }
        klass_name = #{ association_name.to_s.singularize.classify }
        klass_name.where(#{ name.underscore }_id: id)
      end
    EOS
```

Based on column names, and well one of them is causing this problem.

Comment: There is some problem with things not yet specified in the answer. `Gemfile.lock` might help, but please don't paste it right into the question, some sort of pastebin might help.

Comment: which kind of db had you use?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I don't think it's of any use. In the given example data doesn't even get into the database, and serialization algorithms are the same.

Comment: @D-side no, I could propose the specific way for postgresql

Comment: @D-side I discovered WHAT is causing the issue but not WHY

Comment: @D-side look at my updated question.

Comment: @DanStayntouch Mongo, wow. Why not just use embedded documents then? The issue might be related to the fact those are ActiveRecord's serializers, they might not be fit for other ORM/ODMs like for Mongo.

Comment: @DanStayntouch if you wish I'll add an an answwr an alternative to this for postgre db?

Comment: @D-side I am using both mysql and mongoid. What I created was a bridge between the two databases. This bridge builds methods on the fly, which apparently one of them overrode an active record default.

Comment: Seems likely. It should be easy to detect,  before defining a method check whether it exists and raise an exception if so.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to serialize a field as a hash

I saw your try to mix `MySQL` with `NoSQL` to achieve the good serialization. So my answer will specfic for the task, but applicable for `PostgreSQL` database only. I propose you alternative approach for storing hashes in the DB, using the [gem](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore)[hstore](/questions/tagged/hstore). The declaration, and usage will as follows:

```
class Classification
   serialize :dynamic_fields, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end

c = Classification.new
c.dynamic_fields = { '0' => {'field'=>'a','type'=>1}, '1' => {'field'=>'b','type'=>2} }
c.dynamic_fields['0'] # => {'field'=>'a','type'=>1}
```